# Ubuntu - Touchpad Synaptics GUI?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there no GUI for synaptics? like on Windows, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Since I installed Ubuntu a few months ago I was looking for a way to customize the touchpad gestures and other features like on Windows, like the 3 finger gestures and the palm detection.

But there doesn't seem to appear any when I look it up

Is there no such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a tool called *qsynaptics* which worked on older version of Ubuntu, but I think it may have been abandoned.  You could try it here: http://qsynaptics.sourceforge.net/.   More information is also available [here](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2006/12/10/tweaking-your-synaptics-touchpad-laptops-ubuntu-6061-610/).

Comment: You can definitely still use it - it's finding an open source tool which has a GUI which will be difficult.

Comment: Maybe gpointing-device-settings  <br/>

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings